# yii:passing parameter in js

Tags: java, yii

I am trying to pass selected id to js on click of button.

My code is like this:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{email}',
    'buttons'=>array
    (
        'email' => array
        (
            'label'=>'Send an e-mail to this user',
             'click'=>'function($data->userId){
                var y=confirm("Are you sure to send mail to this user?");
                if(y==true){
                    window.location="todoList/sendEmail/$data->userId";
                }
            }',

        ),

    ),
),
```

Here i am not able to get userid inside js.

What can i do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok i found out answer to my question myself.My working code is:

```
 array(
'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
'template'=>'{email}',
'buttons'=>array
(   'email' => array
    (
        'label'=>'Send an e-mail to this user',
        'click'=>'function(){
          return confirm("Are you sure to send mail to this user?");

        }',
        'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("todoList/sendEmail", array("id"=>$data->userId))',
    ),
),
```

),